# Login restriction

Tags: java, authentication, resultset

First time to try Java.

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM admin";

        try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             Connection con= (Connection) 
             DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///mcdc","root","");
             Statement st=con.createStatement();
             rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
             String me = aname.getText();
             String passs = String.valueOf(apass.getPassword());
             String username1=rs.getString("username");
             String password1=rs.getString("password");
             JFrame frm = new JFrame();


          int tmp=0;

         while(tmp < 3) {  
         if(rs.next()){

        if((!me.equals(username1)) && (!passs.equals(password1)))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frm, "INVALID! ", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             aname.setText("");
             apass.setText("");   
        }
        else
        {
        this.setVisible(false);
        new admin_menu().setVisible(true);
        } 

        }

        } 
        tmp++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frm, "You screwed up! ", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }   
        con.close();
    catch(Exception er){
    JFrame frm = new JFrame();
    System.err.println("Exception: " + er.getMessage());
    }
```

Exception:

> Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed.

I'm trying to validate login and this is the error message I got.

Comment: Is that the whole error?

Comment: @immibis yup thats all i got

Comment: You could display the stack trace (`er.printStackTrace()`) to show you which line it was on...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use "int tmp" for? If i get you correctly can you please try to remove int i and while tmp<3 loop.

Comment: On which line do you get the error. Can you please print the stack trace